# Syntax error when creating role with password?

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm writing a script that will create a Postgres user with a certain password based on two environment variables. However, the following code won't work and I have no idea why.

```
export TESTING_DATABASE_USERNAME="yoshi"
export TESTING_DATABASE_PASSWORD="yoshi"
#...
CREATE ROLE $TESTING_DATABASE_USERNAME WITH LOGIN PASSWORD "$TESTING_DATABASE_PASSWORD";
------------------------------------------------------
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""yoshi""
LINE 1: CREATE ROLE yoshi WITH LOGIN PASSWORD "yoshi";
```

When I remove the quotes around `$TESTING_DATABASE_PASSWORD`, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "yoshi"
LINE 1: CREATE ROLE yoshi WITH LOGIN PASSWORD yoshi;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use single quotes.

```
LINE 1: CREATE ROLE yoshi WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'yoshi';
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32224182)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not sure how "proper" it is.

```
export TESTING_DATABASE_PASSWORD="yoshi"
TESTING_DATABASE_PASSWORD="'$TESTING_DATABASE_PASSWORD'"
#...
CREATE ROLE $TESTING_DATABASE_USERNAME WITH LOGIN PASSWORD $TESTING_DATABASE_PASSWORD;
```